# Django; TemplateDoesNotExist error - blog app

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

Im trying to create a blog application following an oline tutorial but an struggling with loading some templates.

It seems as if the templates in blog/templates/blog/... cannot be found.

The page http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/ loads fine. Included below is the current code from the settings.py, views.py and urls.py file.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

... 

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # third party installs go here.
    'products',
    'pages',
    'blog',
]

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404

# Create your views here.

from .models import BlogPost
def blog_post_list_view(request):
    qs = BlogPost.objects.all()  # queryset -> list of python objects
    template_name = 'blog/blog_post_list.html'
    context = {"object_list": qs}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def blog_post_create_view(request):
    # create objects
    #template_name = 'blog/blog_post_create.html'
    context = {"form": None}
    return render(request, "blog/blog_post_create.html", context)


def blog_post_detail_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    template_name = 'blog_post_detail.html'
    context = {"object": obj}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def blog_post_update_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    template_name = 'blog_post_update.html'
    context = {"object": obj, 'form': None}
    return render(request, template_name, context)


def blog_post_delete_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, slug=slug)
    template_name = 'blog_post_delete.html'
    context = {"object": obj}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    blog_post_create_view,
    blog_post_detail_view,
    blog_post_list_view,
)

app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:slug>/', blog_post_detail_view),
    path('', blog_post_list_view),
    path('new-post', blog_post_create_view),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different paths to your templates (missing 'blog/'):

```
template_name = 'blog/blog_post_list.html'
template_name = 'blog_post_detail.html'
template_name = 'blog_post_update.html'
```

You also need to reassure that you have made your templates here:

```
blog/templates/blog/blog_post_list.html <...>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! hadn't realised that not updating the other views would cause the error..